# FCM - What is the limitation of sending messages/minute using API?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I got a few questions

1. what is the limitation of sending messages/minute using API?
2. If there was a limitation, what will happen when exceeding the limitation?
3. The arrival rate is 30%~40%, I would like to know how to increase this rate.

For Android, you can send up to 240 messages/minute and 5,000 messages/hour to a single device. [Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#device_throttling)

But what if I send up to 10000 devices with 100 messages in one minute, would some of the messages be lost?

Thank you !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

I would recommend following the rates stated in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#throttling-and-scaling). Just a general rule to not send too many requests at a time. Usually, you'll get [`5XX` or `429` error](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/ErrorCode#:%7E:text=QUOTA_EXCEEDED,contact%20Firebase%20support.) when you're sending too many notifications. When this happens, you need to implement exponential back-off in your [retry mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44480788/20447561).

As for the arrival rate, I'm assuming you're talking about delivery rate.
This can be caused by several factors like battery saving features, message priority, message lifespan or issue with FCM backend. It’ll be challenging to pinpoint or even narrow down what is the specific cause of low delivery on a public forum without going into project-specific details. I would recommend reaching out to [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support) as they can offer personalized help.